# Changes made in dotnet core app is not completely reflecting in the published dlls

Tags: .net-core, iis, deployment

I have dotnet core app that is running on IIS. I made a few changes published the project and replaced the dlls on the server. Only 50%(approx) changes reflected on the server. I tried deploying on multiple IISes but facing the same issue.

Reading a few docs and forums I have gotten a suggestion of resetting the IIS but that is very risky. Please provide a solution and explain why this could be happening. (BTW the changes are working as expected on local machine)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your server or IIS may be caching a previous version of your application, preventing newer DLLs from loading. You could try restarting IIS and clearing its cache to force the server to load the new DLL. Run the iisreset command by opening a command prompt as an administrator on the server. Of course, this approach will result in a brief downtime of your application during the restart.